# How can I access class instance members and methods from the class itself

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that will create a instance from a class and do some operations on some of its members

```js
function presetInstance<T>(baseClass: any, members: Array<keyof T>) {
  const instance: T = new baseClass();

  // ...
}
```

It works but it leads to code that feels like it should improved:

```js
const instance = presetInstance<BaseClass>(BaseClass, ['foo', 'bar']);
```

Is there a way to only write this ?

```js
const instance = presetInstance(BaseClass, ['foo', 'bar']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a type such as this:

```
interface IConstructor<T> {
    new(): T;
}
```

Now, change the function signature to:

```
presetInstance<T>(baseClass: IConstructor<T>, members: Array<keyof T>)
```

This way, typescript can infer that `baseClass` creates an instance of `T` when constructed with `new`.

[TS Playground example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2IDOYoCuCYmUAPACoB8yA3gFDJPIgQDuAFAJQBcyFAbnoBfevRgEQxYNmQAHKBBwQwqXGDhSIlKhwBGcZegA2hnHwzY8hYqR0AaZAFsITvdHPIAglChwAnmQA1hD+mDD8VFx0jMgIVmDIoHiaSHwUyAC8LOzIBkamODjcQqL0CIU4yABChhAmZjHMyDCYmFnIAOStmJ1CzQZQHZ2DfSJiCkoqailaHLUFZo4A2t1tnY4jcFCdALpcQkA).